# MS Access 2007 - Join Select Query with a table in update

Tags: ms-access

I´m trying to update a third table with the result of a select query - I know how to do this on mysql but access makes insane :)

I have the following statement:

```
UPDATE ceilings LEFT JOIN
(SELECT ceiling_number AS cc, Count(type=3) AS st FROM ceiling INNER JOIN materials ON ceiling.material_number = materials.id GROUP BY ceiling.ceiling_number)  AS q
ON q.cc=ceilings.ceilingid SET ceilings.stairs = q.st;
```

but it does not update tables and when I want to execute the statement i get the error:

> "Operation must use an updateable query"

Would be great if someone could help me with this.

Comment: GROUP BY/Totals Query is always given READ ONLY.

Comment: Can't you use stored procedures? Then you can use SQL queries in Access and also its much faster for performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update queries won't work with several types of other queries, including things like Group by, Totals, CrossTabs, or queries with left or right joins (in combination with inner joins).

There are a couple of solutions around this problem depending on your comfort level with Access and VBA.

1. Create a temporary table first. Write the results of your query to the temporary table, then use the temporary table to update the results of your ceilings table.
2. Use VBA to create and store the values of the non-update-able query, then using recordsets, loop thru your records and update the values in your ceilings table.

Comment: so what is the best workaround?
use vba to store the select query?
and then write it back with an update statement?

Comment: It's a matter of preference. I like to take the simpler route of creating a temporary table, then use that to update your celilings table. Just don't forget to delete the contents of your temporary before each use.